# I can't install Quantum Espresso in MacOS High Sierra

Tags: installation, configure, quantum-computing

I have problems while executing ./configure. I am quite new with these things and I don't really know where the problem is. In configure.log file I get the following errors (I couldn't upload it because it was too heavy):

1. gfortran: error: unrecognized command-line option '-V'
2. gfortran: fatal error: no input files
3. collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
4. configure: failed program was:
   |       program main
   |       call dgemm
   |       end

Does anyone know which is the real problem?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this link](https://sites.google.com/a/ncsu.edu/cjobrien/tutorials-and-guides/pwscf), running

```
sudo ./configure --disable-parallel --with-internal-FFTW --with-internal-blas --with-internal-lapack ARCH="mac686"
```

is generally recommended on Mac. I just installed Quantum Espresso successfully using it.

Comment: It doesn't work in my case. I don't know if it could me related with the software version, because it is quite old and I am not able to update it any more...

Comment: Do you mean the version of QE, or the version of Mac OS?